# jquery CSS calc() function

Tags: jquery, css

i came across this page [CSS  LINK](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calcltexpressiongt)
i could't help but love the idea of that to calculate the outcome of different units...
however i tried this :

```
$('selector').css({'width':'calc(100%-20px)'});
```

but it doesn't work... anyone has any ideas how this works , or why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery does not support the `calc()` value, and neither does any of the current browsers.

See a comparison here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29

In your example, yo can just use margins on the inner element instead:

```
<div class="parent"><div class="elem"></div></div>

.parent{
    width:100%;
    background:green;
}
.elem{
    margin: 0 10px;
    background:blue;
}
```

This way, `.elem` will be 100% - 20px wide.

Comment: thanks man ...
I think it should be illegal for a browser not fully implimented 100% lol this is nightttttmare waste of our time trying to fix all the mis-implimented borwsers

Comment: no it's not about the browser, it's about the CSS version. The browsers are fine, but they still don't fully support CSS3

Comment: thats what i mean they should not put css3 out until every browser fully supports it... because it will just add another thing we have to start using work arounds for...or hacks

Comment: They haven't “put CSS3 out”. You are looking at working drafts for the standardisation process.

Comment: This is outdated - [calc is supported in some browsers now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc#AutoCompatibilityTable).

Answer (score 6):

jQuery supports the calc(). I have used this so many times:

1. `$(".content-section").css('width','calc('+contentSectionWidth+'% - 15px)');`
2. `$(".content-section").css('width','calc(100% - 15px)');`

Comment: The above comments are outdated. calc does work with jQuery now, as per this example.

Comment: Example 2 has a mismatched quote that I am unable to remove because it's considered to be too minor of an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Some parts of CSS3 are well-supported. Other parts aren't. That's why it has been split into modules, which are in [various stages of agreement and implementation](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work). We are a long, long way from even having a complete range of CSS3 specifications, let alone widespread browser support.

So CSS Level 3 Selectors is the most stable specification, having made Recommendation and been implemented by quite a few browsers and other tools (though still, it will take a while for all mainstream browsers to support it well). Several of the other PRs and CRs have enough support in the latest browsers to be of interest.

But “CSS3 Values and Units” is still only an early-stage Working Draft, and is very likely to change significantly before reaching Recommendation. In fact given that no browsers have implemented `calc()`since the draft was begun years ago, it looks unlikely at this point that this feature will become standard. If you want to stay within the realm of well-supported stuff, you need to stick with CSS 2.1.

In the meantime, saying things like `100%-20px` has to be done with nested elements, margins and padding.

Comment: i have tried many work arounds but it is doing my heading because almost everytime something will mess it up... i could convert the width or height into percentage but css2.1 doesn't allow decimals in percentages which doesn't always look all that pretty lol

Comment: CSS 2.1 does allow decimal places in percentages. It doesn't entirely solve relative calculation or pixel-rounding problems though.

Answer (score 1):

[Ravi verma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19353966/945370) is correct.

What I would like to add is the reason why your code wasn't working. When doing addition and subtraction with `calc`, you need to have whitespace preceding and proceeding the operator.

From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

> The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. The operand of calc(50% -8px) for instance will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while the operand of calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a minus sign and a length. Even further, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage.
>   The * and / operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If the calc issue is only occurring on production (during minification), check your minifier.  We found that the default C# minifier (~3 years ago, ~2019?) failed on the calc function... producing similar issues.

For us, switching from the default VS2017 C# minifier to SquishIt solved that issue.  Other minifiers also solved the issue, though SquishIt ended up being the 'winner' of those we tried.

Best wishes and happy coding,
Michael M.